# Unwanted calling onClick event on button after pressed enter

Tags: asp.net, button, textbox, onclick

net web page I have textBox and button.

I added onClick for button.

Problem is that if I  click enter in textBox it also call onClick event for button. I understand why.

My code is here:

**TextBox is in view:**

```
                      <asp:View ID="BlView" runat="server">
                           <p class="tabHead"> BLACK LIGHT LABEL DATA </p>
                            <table class="tab">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" class="label" Text="BARCODE" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="bl_tb_barcode" runat="server" BorderWidth="1px" 
                                            class="textBox"  Width="700"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                     </asp:View>
```

**Button code is here:**

```
       <div class="divPrinter">
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" class="dropDownList" Width="250" Height="35" 
            ID="cbPrinters" style="margin-top:80px"/>
        <asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" class="btnPrint" style="margin-top:80px"
            Width="120" Height="35"  Text="Print" onclick="BtnPrintClick"  />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it you don't want the `Enter` key to have any effect? If so, add this tag to your textboxes:

```
onKeyDown = "return (event.keyCode != 13)"
```

so it would be like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="bl_tb_barcode" runat="server" BorderWidth="1px" 
     class="textBox"  Width="700" onKeyDown="return (event.keyCode != 13)"/>
```

As a side note, `onKeyDown` is a Javascript event, so it won't execute on the server. The code will return `false` so a postback will not occur.